# ARM: memory address ... why is it 0x04030201...?

Tags: memory, arm

can someone explain to me why we represent, the memory address itself in this way:
"Word on address =0x00":
0x04030201,
I know each of the 01, 02, 03, 04 is one byte, but can someone explain to me where that byte is, what does it represent? a memory cell in a register? I am totally confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An address, memory or otherwise is really no different than an address on a building.  Sometimes systematically and well chosen, sometimes haphazardly.  In any case some buildings are fire stations, some are grocery stores, some are apartments and some are houses and so on.  But the addressing system used by a city or nation can get your item directly to that building.

when we talk about addresses in software it is no different.  the processor at the lowest level doesnt know or care there is an address bus, an interface where the address is projected outside the processor.  As you add on each layer of logic, like an onion, around the processor and eventually other chips, memory, usb controllers, hard drive controllers, etc.  Just like the parts of an address on an envelope, portions of that address are extracted and the read or write command is delivered to the individual logic who wears that address on the side of their building.

You cant simply ask what is address 0x04030201 without any context.  Addresses schemes are fairly specific their system there are hundreds or thousands or tens of thousands of arm based systems all of which have different address schemes and that address could point to nothing, with nobody to answer that request dies and possibly hangs the processor or it could be some ram or it could be a register in a usb controller or video controller or disk drive controller.

Generally you have read and write operations, in this example that would be once the letter makes it to the individual at the address on the envelope the contents of the letter contain instructions.  Do this (write), or get this and mail it back (read).  And the individual in the case of hardware just does what it is told without asking.  If it is a read then it performs a read within the context of whatever that device is.  A hard disk controller a read of a particular address might be a temperature sensor, or a status register that contains the speed at which the motor is spinning, or it might be some data that had been recently read from the hard disk.  In the simple case of memory it is likely just some memory, some bytes.

how much stuff is being read is also another item that is specified on the processors bus, and this varies from processor to processor as to what is available to the programmer.  Sometimes you can request to read or write individual bytes, sometimes 16 bit items or 32 or 64, etc.

then you get into address translation.  Using the mail analogy this is kind of like having your mail forwarded to another address.  You write one address on the letter, the post office has a forwarding request for that address, so they change your address to the new address and then complete the delivery of the letter.  When you hear of a memory management unit, MMU, and in some uses of the word virtual memory, that is the kind of thing that is going on.  Lets say that we want to make the programmers life simple and we tell every one that ram starts at address 0x00000000.  that makes it much easier to have a compiler choose memory locations where our variables and arrays and programs live, it can compile every program the same way based on that address.  But how is it that I can have many programs running at once if they all share the same memory.  well they dont.  One program thinks it is writing to address 0x00000000 but in reality there is some unique address which can be completely different that does belong only to that program lets say address 0x10000000, the mmu is like the mail carrier at the post office that changes the address, the processor knows from information as to which task is running that it needs to convert 0x00000000 to 0x10000000.  When another program accesses what it thinks is 0x00000000 it might have that address changed to 0x11000000, and another 0x00000000 might map to physical address 0x12000000.  The address that actually hits the memory is called the physical address, the address that the program uses is called the virtual address, it isnt real it is destined to be changed.

This mmu stuff not only allows for compilers and programmers to have an easier job but also the mmu allows us to protect one program or the operating system from another.  Application programs run at a certain protection level which the mmu uses to know what that user is allowed to do.  if a program generates a virtual address that is outside of its address space, say the system has 1 gig of memory and the program tries to address 1 gig plus a little bit more.  the mmu instead of converting that to a physical address instead generates an interrupt to the processor which switches that processor into a mode that has more permissions, basically the operating system, and the operating system can then decided to try to use that other kind of virtual memory and allow the program to have more memory, or it may kill the program and put up a warning message to the user that such and such program has had a protection fault and was killed.

Address schemes for computers are generally a lot more thought out than developers that number houses in new neighborhoods, but not always, but it is not that far removed from an address on an envelope.  You pick apart bits in the address and those chunks of bits mean something and deliver this processor request to the individual at that address.  How the bits are parsed is very specific to the processor and platform and in some cases is dynamic or programmable on the fly, so if your next question is what is 0xabcd on my system, we may still not be able to help you.  You may have to do more research or give is a lot of info...

Answer (score 1):

Think of memory as an array of bytes. 'Word on address' can mean different things depending what the CPU designers consider a Word. In your case it seems a Word is 32 bits long.

So `'Word on address=0x00: 0x04030201'` means:

'Beginning at memory cell `0x00` (inclusive), the 'next' four bytes are `0x04 0x03 0x02 0x01`.

Also, depending on the endianness of your CPU the meaning of 'next' changes. It could be that `0x04` is stored in cell `0x00`, or that `0x01` is stored there.

Comment: thanks, but why memory cell? Is each memory cell 1 byte long or is it just chosen arbitrary as 1 byte long? and memory in this case is it meant RAM Memory or can it also be any kind of memory like some Hard drive memory...? Furthermore, the adress 0x04030201... is it the POINTER to a physical memory or is this the memory containing the information to get itself?